# Creating or using interface for a Facebook/LinkedIn style link post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, facebook, linkedin-api

I wish to add the ability to like Facebook and LinkedIn paste a URL into a textbox area and it picks up the content and gives a preview aswell as linking to the page/article.

Does anyone know of any existing jQuery etc. that exists and makes this possible for me to implement to a page on my website?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways in doing this. One such way is http://markserbol.github.io/urlive/ which uses JQuery, but there are several for JS, PHP etc.

Comment: Thanks this one isn't too bad, although i would like if like facebook i could add a comment or description to it before posting.

Comment: https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Facebook-Link-Preview allows comments/descriptions. Is that good?